# Need help to solve DSA : Find position of set bit in java

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

```
class Solution {
    static int findPosition(int N) {
        if((N&(N-1)) != 0) return -1;
        
        int pos = 1;
        while(N!=0){
            if((N&1) == 1){
                return pos;
            } else {
                pos++;
                N>>=1;
            }
        }
        return -1;    }
};
```

In this code, if the N is 5, then in while loop, (5&1) == 1 which satisfy the condition and it suppose to return 1, but the code is returning -1. Please explain where exactly I'm missing the concept

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
if((N&(N-1)) != 0) return -1;
```

`Here it checks wether the value is power of 2 or not and 5 is not a power of 2 thats why it returns -1`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

It's much easier to move the `1` bit than to shift the number. Also bit positions are counted from 0 instead of 1:

```java
class Solution {
    static int findPosition(int N) {
      if((N & (N-1)) != 0) {
        return -1;
      }
      
      for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++){
        if ((N & (1 << i)) != 0){
          return i;
        }
      }

      return -1;    
    }
}
```

> if the N is 5, then in while loop, (5&1) == 1 which satisfy the condition and it suppose to return 1, but the code is returning -1

This is caused by your first check:

```
if((N&(N-1)) != 0) return -1;
```

This code checks that your number has only one bit set to `1`, but the number `5` in binary is `0b101` which has two bits set to `1`. That's why you never reach your `while` loop:

```
5: 0b101
   AND
4: 0b100
--
   0b100 != 0
```

PS: There is another clever way to get that position:

```java
class Solution {
    static int findPosition(int N) {
      var pos = Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(N);
      return pos != 32 ? pos : -1;
    }
}
```